How to make legend of a pcolormesh showing a polar projection, and display the value the cursor is hovering over?
I have two 2D Dimensional arrays of size [360][91] with values ranging from -1 to 13 that I am currently displaying as a radial projection using pcolormesh. For exemple, the value situated at [45][70] would be displayed at 45 degrees and -70 distance from center (my use case requires me to range Y starting center at 90 and the edge to be 0, hence why my plot ranges from -90 to 0).

When I display those arrays as rectangles using imshow() I can see the value of the position my cursor is hovering over on the top right corner of the window, but when using pcolormesh, all I get is the angle information. My value is correctly shown by the colormap, but I'd like to have the feedback of the cursor too.
Additionally, using subplot.legend() only displays an empty little rectangle with no error messages, which is really strange and doesn't give me a direction as to where I'm supposed to look into. The result I expected was to have a legend displaying which color is associated to which value, but I couldn't find anything in the documentation, and the online exemples only show polar projections legend for curves, and they're not pcolormeshs.
Here is a version of my code but with randomized arrays for minimal reproducibility :
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[10,10])
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121, projection='polar')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, projection='polar')

# 2D Dimensional arrays of size [360][91] with values ranging from -1 to 13
# this randomized exemple looks different than my result but the functionalities 
# I search should be the same.
arr_1 = np.random.randint(-1, 13, size=(91, 360))
arr_2 = np.random.randint(-1, 13, size=(91, 360))

used_theta = np.radians(np.arange(0,361,1))
used_rad = np.arange(-92,0,1)

theta,rad = np.meshgrid(used_theta, used_rad) #rectangular plot of polar data
X = theta
Y = rad

ax1.pcolormesh(X, Y, arr_1 ) #X,Y & data2D must all be same dimensions
ax1.set_theta_zero_location("S")
ax1.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax1.legend()


ax2.pcolormesh(X, Y, arr_2, cmap= 'plasma') #X,Y & data2D must all be same dimensions
ax2.set_theta_zero_location("S")
ax2.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax2.legend()

plt.show()


I'm using matplotlib version 3.9.2 and cursor position is shown correctly, both angle and radius. For the "legend" question, the associated color should be visualized using fig.colorbar with associated mappable as argument, i.e. mesh created by pcolormesh. You should change your code as:
fig.colorbar(p1)

